# A WiFi hotspot with a high transmission power

Tags: wifi, access-point

I'm looking for an access point with the following requirements:

1. it should have a tramission power of at least 20dbm, but 26dbm or higher is desired.
2. It should support both 2.4GHz and 5GHz, though it is not crticial.
3. it must support a LAN input.
   4.It can be delievered at Israel (via a shipping or a local store).

Thanks